# Stopping time and starting several programs with bash

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash

I'm currently trying to measure the time a program needs to finish when I start it 8 times at the same time.

Now I would really like to write a bash or something that starts the program several times with different parameters and measures the time until all of them are finished.
I think I would manage to start my program 8 times by simply using `&` at the end but then I don't know how to know when they stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wait` to wait for background jobs to finish.

```
#!/bin/sh
program &
program &
wait
```

will wait until both instances of `program` exit.

Answer (score 0):

use `jobs` to see whats still running, if you need 8 you can do

```
if jobs | wc -l < 8 then  command &
```

Not working code but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `time` command to measure the time consumption of a program, so perhaps something like

```
#!/bin/bash
time yourprogram withoneargument
time yourprogram with three arguments
...etc
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Bystrup supplies the `time` command, which will time the execution of your programs.  Mr. Politowski and user2814958 supply the `&` operator, which will run programs in the background, allowing you to start them at the same time.  If you combine these, you're most of the way there, except the output from `time` for the different commands will be jumbled, and it will be hard to tell which output pertains to which command.

One way to overcome this issue is to shunt the output into different files:

```
/usr/bin/time program1 2>/tmp/program1.time &
/usr/bin/time program2 2>/tmp/program2.time &
```

Note that I'm redirecting the standard error (file descriptor 2) into the files; `time` writes its output on the standard error instead of the standard output.  Also note my use of the full path to `time`.  Some shells have a built-in `time` command that behaves differently, such as writing output directly to the terminal instead of standard error.